# how can I select all columns of a dataframe, which partially match strings in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching

Suppose I have a Dataframe like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': [4, 5, 6], 'ber': [7, 8, 9]})
```

Given a list of "filter" strings like `mylist = ['oo', 'ba']`, how can I select all columns in `df` whose name partially match any of the strings in `mylist`? For this example, the expected output is `{'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': [4, 5, 6]}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.filter` with `regex` to do that.

```
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2, 3], 'bar': [4, 5, 6], 'ber': [7, 8, 9]})

# sample list of strings
mylist = ['oo', 'ba']

# join the list to a single string
matches = '|'.join(mylist)

# use regex to filter the columns based on the string
df_out = df.filter(regex=matches)
```